# Overflow:hidden not working on mobile browser

Tags: css, mobile

Im using overflow:hidden to hide my unglam div in my webpage, it works well in all web browser but not in mobile browser. Anyone can help?

```
body
{
    margin: auto;
    display:block;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    height:800px;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try adding following line in your html

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height">
```

and test on your phone. Maybe this should help.

Comment: It works for chrome browser! but this meta tag isnt fixing the issue on webview.

Answer (score 2):

Add a wrapper inside your `body` tag and apply the `overflow-x: hidden` to that wrapper

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which mobile browser you're using, `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` may not be supported. Use `overflow: hidden` instead to cover all bases and be cross browser compatible.

Comment: after i change to overflow:hidden, it is still not workable. Im testing it on android. mayb u can hav a look on it. beauty.org.sg